# Try-catch in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have to load a log that should fit in the pattern. Unfortunately some records don't.
It occurs as an error when I'm trying to store data in HCatalog.

Is it possible to store the records that fit the pattern in the HCalatlog, and keep other in a file for further processing?

Or maybe it is possible to do something like try-catch in Pig?

I can't find any solution on but it must be simple - I just don't believe nobody faced that problem earlier!

I will be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited Answer**
People have faced this issue before, but the answer is usually "UDF".  Unfortunately, I think that's probably the best answer for your question: a UDF that performs the data validation using java or python try/catch error handling.

Another answer is to use [`SPLIT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#SPLIT) to evaluate the data in the field and direct the data into the appropriate alias.  This is a common method of handling non-expected data.

**Original Answer:**
In version .12 of Pig, you have the [`ASSERT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#assert) operator, which isn't as good as try/catch, but it's better than nothing.

From the docs:

```
Suppose we have relation A.

A = LOAD 'data' AS (a0:int,a1:int,a2:int);

DUMP A;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
(8,4,3)
Now, you can assert that a0 column in your data is >0, fail if otherwise

ASSERT A by a0 > 0 'a0 should be greater than 0';
```

Comment: JamCon - thanks for the answer. As you said -  it's better that nothing but I'm looking for some king of general error management. Im my case, the log contains more columns than expected, so it doesn't fit pattern. I won't be able to use ASSERT if I don't knon what may be wrong. It's really hasd to believe that Pig doesn't provide such basic functionality... Or maybr it does, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 1):

The `ASSERT` method in JamCon's answer is often helpful, but as you say, your particular issue can't be addressed by it. If you are simply looking to test for the presence of extra columns, one possible workaround would be to load your data as normal, but in the `AS` clause, add an extra column called `error:chararray`. Typically, you would expect this to be `NULL`, but if there are extra columns, it won't be. So

`SPLIT a INTO good IF error IS NULL, bad IF error IS NOT NULL;`

to separate out the lines which have extra records.

Ugly, but in this particular case it should work for you.